# Can't find eclipse project anymore after pushing to GitHub

Tags: java, git, missing-data

Made a GitHub repo and went to Team > Share Project.
It disappeared from my workspace and went to the git perspective.
I clicked Push Branch 'master' and now all my code is gone.

Please help!! How can I get my code back / where did it go?

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but I’d wager that it’s still there somewhere and should be easy enough to get back.

Comment: Do you know the location of your workspace/project? Check there. Also, do you see it on GitHub? If yes, you can just clone it.

Comment: not on github, or in the workspace.  The project completely disappeared from the workspace.

Comment: Did you mange to restore it back? This piece of trash just works so terribly